# A non well formed numeric value encountered when try to calculated total value on blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am try to calculate total cart fees inside blade template on ecommerce project and inside foreach and if but This error appears on this line inside if and foreach

```
  @if(session('cart')) 
  @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

     <?php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ?>

  @endforeach
  @endif
```

A non well formed numeric value encountered and refer error on this line :

```
 <?php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ?>
```

i am using php 7.3.3

Comment: First of all, what is $total ? Do you set it to 0 somewhere ? Did you tried to debug what are yours $details['price'] and quantity values ? `dump($details)`

Comment: yes i am define total outside if section      <?php $total = 0 ?> and data binding for price $details["price"] appears correctly on the front and when i try dump

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "name" => "Nutella Waffle II"
  "quantity" => 2
  "price" => "40 L.E"
  "content" => "its dulications"
  "featured" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/posts/1565309562seller-2-200x200.png"
]

Comment: As you can see `$detals['price']` is not a well formed number, its a string: `"40 L.E."` that is why you get the notice. IMHO a column named price shoud be a number, without any currency, if you need a currency just use another field for it.

Comment: you also shouldn't use "<?php ?>" in blade templates. Blade engine offers you the possibility to write php within two brackets "{{ $putYourCodeHere }}"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's kind of problem. Try to parse your values ​​like this

$total += (float)$details['price'] * (float)$details['quantity']

Comment: A cast can remove the notice but it hides a problem, I think it's better to have the correct field type in the database.

Comment: I agree, that it is a solution too